# documentation for Python statsmodel seasonal_decompose() using convolution filter

Tags: time-series, python, statsmodels

I would like to better understand how the `seasonal_decompose()` function from python `statsmodel` module works.

The documentation is a little sparse as it only states:

```
This is a naive decomposition. More sophisticated methods should be preferred.

The additive model is Y[t] = T[t] + S[t] + e[t]

The multiplicative model is Y[t] = T[t] * S[t] * e[t]

The seasonal component is first removed by applying a convolution filter to 
the data. The average of this smoothed series for each period is the returned
seasonal component.
```

Is there any further documentation on this method? How is the trend extracted after estimating the seasonal component? I would prefer exploring theoretical explanations rather than directly dive into the code.